# Should I install all the SDKs in Android Studio's SDK manager?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

How it works? Like, if I have android 12 sdk installed, will the compiled apk work in all the lower versions?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, dumb question, but the subject isn't really googlable, so don't blame me. I've found the answer later, not even googling for it.

All the higher version SDKs are compatible with the lower versions. That's it.